# How do calculate a fee from a given percentage

Tags: percentages

**Scenario:**

I want to buy a share in a company.

- Cost per share = 50,000USD
- Number of shares to buy = 0.5
- Transaction fees = 0.2%

---

**Calculations:**

- Convert fee percentage to a decimal : 0.2 / 100 = 0.002
- Convert decimal fee to amount to subtract from shares : 1 - 0.002 = 0.998
- Calculate shares bought after fees : 0.5 * 0.998 = 0.499

---

**Two part question:**

1. Is the calculation correct?
2. Is there a better, simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to spend $d$ dollars for shares and that amount should include the commission $c$ (expressed as a fraction, not a percent). Let $s$ be the amount that will go to shares. Then
$$
(1+c)s = d
$$
so
$$
s = \frac{d}{1+c}.
$$

That is not the same as what you calculated, which is $s(1-c)$. But when $c$ is very small (as it is in this case) they are very close. You can check the difference numerically.

Comment: I don't thin the above formula transformation is correct.
(1+c)s=d cannot be transformed to d=s / (1 + c).
s = d / (1 + c) - sure
Even if you provide exact number the the `d` that is supposed to include the amount for shares + fees becomes less in value compared to `s`

Comment: @Tek Thanks for finding the error in my algebra. I interchanged $d$ and $s$ in the conclusion. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken, but I don't think transaction fees are calculated in that way.  If you buy two shares, spending $\$100,000$ then you will have to pay an **additional** $\$200$ in transaction fees.

Therefore, the fraction of outlay that goes toward the transaction fee is

$$\frac{200}{100200} ~\text{rather than}~ \frac{200}{100000}.$$

The natural question is, since my proposed interpretation leads to less profit for the bank/brokerage house, why would they accept such an interpretation?  **Answer** : because the math is easier for their bookkeepers to understand.

Actually, I could be mistaken; I simply suspect that my interpretation is how the calculations are actually done.